BigQuery Challenge: pivoting customer table with cost splitting
I have a table like:



ID
TYPE
NAME
FULL COST
COST SPLIT




a1
customer
john
6
2


a1
customer
jack
6
2


a1
customer
frank
6
2


a1
environment
dev
6
6


a1
sales
full
6
6


a2
customer
antony
15
3


a2
customer
jeff
15
3


a2
customer
mark
15
3


a2
customer
john
15
3


a2
customer
jack
15
3


a2
environment
test
15
7.5


a2
environment
dev
15
7.5


a2
sales
partial
15
15



In this data, each ID has a full cost which is reported in FULL COST. The COST SPLIT is simply the split of full cost within each TYPE. In ID=a1 for example, the full cost is 6, and since there are 3 customers, cost split is 2. There is only one environment so cost split = 6, and there's only one sales so cost split = 6. Same mechanism for ID=a2.
Now I need to transform the above table in such a way that the types become columns, and the cost split is distributed like below (I won't put the full cost again here, but we can use it if needed):



ID
customer
environment
sales
COST SPLIT




a1
john
dev
full
2


a1
jack
dev
full
2


a1
frank
dev
full
2


a2
antony
test
partial
1.5


a2
jeff
test
partial
1.5


a2
mark
test
partial
1.5


a2
john
test
partial
1.5


a2
jack
test
partial
1.5


a2
antony
dev
partial
1.5


a2
jeff
dev
partial
1.5


a2
mark
dev
partial
1.5


a2
john
dev
partial
1.5


a2
jack
dev
partial
1.5



Can you see the difference? Basically, In the final table, for each ID group I need a row for each TYPE combination; i.e. for a1 -> john - dev - full, jack - dev - full, frank - dev - full. The COST SPLIT now has to be such that the sum of each TYPE value gives me back the COST SPLIT of table 1. So john jack and frank cost 2 each as before, "dev" is repeated 3 times so it's 6, and same goes for "full".
You can see now why for ID=a2 everything becomes 1.5.
I am not sure if I can obtain this with some sort of pivot or some join.
Thanks

Can you add an example of how to calculate the cost in the expected table? e.g. why cost on line a2, antony, test, partial is 1.5?

Hi! Basically in the final table for each ID group I have to make one row for each type combination: john - dev - full, jack - dev - full, frank - dev - full. The COST has to be such the sum of each type gives me back the COST of table one. So john jack and frank cost 2 each, dev is repeated 3 times so it's 6, and same for full. Now you see why in ID=a2 everything is 1.5.

I've updated the question, hopefully it's clearer.

Use below approach
SELECT 
  ID,
  customer,
  environment,
  sales,
  cost / COUNT(DISTINCT environment) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS cost
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ID, name AS customer, cost FROM your_table WHERE type = 'customer'))
JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ID, name AS environment FROM your_table WHERE type = 'environment')) USING(ID)
JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ID, name AS sales FROM your_table WHERE type = 'sales')) USING(ID)  

If applied to sample data in your questions - output is

Note: above is based on some assumptions made which not necessarily the way you want
